# BlackBerry pushing screen without popping

Tags: blackberry

Hi I have two screens which I never wanna pop because they load data from the web and I don't wanna load it all the time. However if I try to navigate from one to another I get a RuntimeException saying that I tried to push a screen that was already displayed. Is there a work around to pushScreen? Something like change screen?

Comment: what you tried ?. show some codes ?

Comment: Separate application logic from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly do what Rupak and Richard are suggesting.  But, let me offer another option, that might require less redesign from what you currently have.

It sounds like you're doing some expensive operation when a `Screen` is instantiated, right?  And you want to avoid doing that multiple times?

Are you pushing your screens like this:

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new FooScreen());

UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new BarScreen());
```

Instead, make sure wherever you push screens **saves the screen**, to be reused later (at least for these two screens you think *should not be popped*).  I usually have something like a `ScreenController` class to handle this.  So, you could do this:

```java
if (_fooScreen == null) {
    _fooScreen = new FooScreen();
}
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(_fooScreen);
```

...

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(_barScreen);
UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(_fooScreen);  // popped but still referenced
```

...

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(_fooScreen); // pushed, but not recreated
```

You're not recreating the screen every time you want to push it, or destroying its state when you pop it.

If this really isn't what you want, and you're convinced that your two screens should really **never** be popped, then maybe they shouldn't be `Screens` at all.  Maybe they should be `Manager` subclasses.

Maybe you only have one `Screen` (not two), which logically manages the content of both of what you originally had as two separate screens.  So, to toggle between them, you would simply have the single `Screen` do this:

```java
add(_fooManager);
remove(_barManager);
```

or

```java
replace(_barManager, _fooManager);   // logically similar to "changing" screens
```

Screens fundamentally are built to use push and pop semantics.  If that doesn't work for you, just use `Manager` subclasses.  Since `Screen` extends `Manager`, that should involve minimal code changes to refactor this way.

You do lose some of the nice transition features for switching screens.  However, since I had to write BlackBerry code before those were available, I already learned to rely on alternative techniques, [such as this one for animating the switching of Fields](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/animation-effect-for-horizontal-field-manager/m-p/1310255#M174265)

Fully separating the **View** layer, from a **Controller** layer, is often the way to go.  However, especially for BlackBerry apps, I do believe that there are some times when adhering too strictly to an MVC architecture just increases code bloat and maintenance, and isn't really necessary to solve problems like you describe.

Anyway, just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Strange gives a very good explanation of BlackBerry screen semantics [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Bring-back-the-screen-to-the-top/td-p/383513). Essentially you should (as Rupak suggests) separate application logic from flow. If you are goingt to allow, or encourage, a user to frequently redisplay a page you should load the data once and keep in in local cache for a reasonable amount of time so that you can redisplay it later.

Comment: I saw Peter on the conference. It was huge pleasure to speak with him :)